# Добавить ОЗУ в ноутбук

Tags: ram

Имеется ноутбук HP ProBook 4545s с двумя слотами для ОЗУ. Стоит одна планка на 4гб. Нужно добавить еще одну планку на 4гб, но не могу разобраться какие должны быть характеристики у второй планки, чтобы все хорошо работало. Точно такой же планки найти в продаже не смог. Маркировка представлена на фото, хочется узнать, за что отвечают обозначения: PC3, 12800S, 11, 10, B2. Какие характеристики должны быть у второй планки?

[image: Фото планки ОЗУ]

Comment: Какая ось? В Диспетчере задач Windows на вкладке Memory показывает объём и тип памяти (у меня в ноуте DDR3), частоту / Speed (1600 MHz) и Form factor (SODIMM). В принципе, этих данных достаточно для покупки: SODIMM, 1600 Мгц, DDR3.

Comment: Я нашел табличку, PC3-12800S означает, что память DDR3, частота 1600Мгц, S - SoDIMM. Но есть еще тайминги, они как я понял тоже должны совпадать.

Comment: Желательно, конечно, чтобы тайминги совпадали. Но это не обязательно. Работать и так будет. Даже планку с другой частотой можно взять (в итоге обе будут работать на частоте меньшей).